# SQL: Alias Column Name for Use in CASE Statement

Tags: sql

Is it possible to alias a column name and then use that in a CASE statement? For example,

```
SELECT col1 as a, CASE WHEN a = 'test' THEN 'yes' END as value FROM table;
```

I am trying to alias the column because actually my CASE statement would be generated programmatically, and I want the column that the case statement uses to be specified in the SQL instead of having to pass another parameter to the program.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I think that MySql and MsSql won't allow this because they will try to find all columns in the CASE clause as columns of the tables in the WHERE clause.

I don't know what DBMS you are talking about, but I guess you could do something like this in any DBMS:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN a = 'test' THEN 'yes' END as value FROM (
   SELECT col1 as a FROM table
) q
```

Comment: Why does this not work if the alias is on a temporary table? I tried using the alias in a WHERE clause condition.

Comment: This is was actually super easy in SQL server also...END AS column_name +1

Answer (score 74):

This:

```
SELECT col1 as a,
       CASE WHEN a = 'test' THEN 'yes' END as value 
  FROM table;
```

...will **not** work.  This **will**:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a = 'test' THEN 'yes' END as value
  FROM (SELECT col1 AS a
          FROM TABLE)
```

Why you wouldn't use:

```
SELECT t.col1 as a,
       CASE WHEN t.col1 = 'test' THEN 'yes' END as value 
  FROM TABLE t;
```

...I don't know.

Comment: maybe 'a' is a slow function that don't worth to run twice.

Comment: How would this work with a WITH clause? The column in the CASE statement is from the WITH clause, so where would the CASE go?

Comment: @OMGPonies thanks for your answer. If t.col1 is a calculated column (e.g. `total = quantity * price` how would one still refer to it? Can we still call it `t.col1`?

Answer (score 5):

@OMG Ponies - One of my reasons of not using the following code

```
SELECT t.col1 as a, 
     CASE WHEN t.col1 = 'test' THEN 'yes' END as value 
FROM TABLE t;
```

can be that the t.col1 is not an actual column in the table. For example, it can be a value from a XML column like

```
Select XMLColumnName.value('(XMLPathOfTag)[1]', 'varchar(max)') 
as XMLTagAlias from Table
```

Answer (score 2):

It should work. Try this

```
Select * from
              (select col1, col2, case when 1=1 then 'ok' end as alias_col
               from table)
        as tmp_table
order by 
       case when @sortBy  = 1 then tmp_table.alias_col end asc
```

Answer (score 1):

I use CTEs to help compose complicated SQL queries but not all RDBMS' support them.  You can think of them as query scope views.  Here is an example in t-sql on SQL server.

```
With localView1 as (
 select c1,
        c2,
        c3,
        c4,
        ((c2-c4)*(3))+c1 as "complex"
   from realTable1) 
   , localView2 as (
 select case complex WHEN 0 THEN 'Empty' ELSE 'Not Empty' end as formula1,
        complex * complex as formula2    
   from localView1)
select *
from localView2
```

Comment: WITH syntax is supported in Oracle 9i+, SQL Server 2005+, and DB2 (dunno version).  In Oracle & SQL Server's case, WITH syntax is just an alternative to inline views.

Answer (score 0):

Nor in MsSql

```
SELECT col1 AS o, e = CASE WHEN o < GETDATE() THEN o ELSE GETDATE() END 
FROM Table1
```

Returns:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid column name 'o'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid column name 'o'.
```

However if I change to CASE WHEN col1... THEN col1 it works

Answer (score 0):

- If you write only equal condition just:
  Select Case columns1 When 0 then 'Value1' 
  when 1 then 'Value2' else 'Unknown' End
- If you want to write greater , Less then or equal you must do like this:
  Select Case When [ColumnsName] >0 then 'value1' When [ColumnsName]=0 Or  [ColumnsName]<0 then
  'value2' 
  Else
  'Unkownvalue' End

From tablename

Thanks
Mr.Buntha Khin

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    a AS [blabla a],
    b [blabla b],
    CASE c
        WHEN 1 THEN 'aaa'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'bbb'
        ELSE 'unknown' 
    END AS [my alias], 
    d AS [blabla d]
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score -1):

Not in MySQL. I tried it and I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score -1):

In MySql, alice name may not work, therefore put the original column name in the CASE statement

```
 SELECT col1 as a, CASE WHEN col1 = 'test' THEN 'yes' END as value FROM table;
```

Sometimes above query also may return error, I don`t know why (I faced this problem in my two different development machine). Therefore put the CASE statement into the "(...)" as below:

```
SELECT col1 as a, (CASE WHEN col1 = 'test' THEN 'yes' END) as value FROM table;
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you just need to add a parenthesis :

```
SELECT col1 as a, (CASE WHEN a = 'test' THEN 'yes' END) as value FROM table;
```

Comment: This doesn't work in SQL server. Returns "Invalid column name 'a'"

Answer (score -4):

make it so easy.

```
select columnnameshow = (CASE tipoventa
when 'CONTADO' then 'contadito'
when 'CREDITO' then 'cred'
else 'no result'
end) from Promocion.Promocion
```

Comment: there's no alias here