# SQL Server - reference previous selection

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm learning SQL, so please bear with me. I was wondering if the following is possible, and if so, how do you reference previous selections?

```
SELECT [col1] as something1, [col2] as something2, 
       <Can I use something1 or something2 in the third selection?> 
  FROM [MyTable] 
 WHERE <Condition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583609/sql-alias-column-name-for-use-in-case-statement) I do not think that this will work in SQL Server.

If you really need to use the aliases you can do:

```
SELECT yoursubquery.something1, yoursubquery.something2, 
  FROM (
        SELECT [col1] as something1, [col2] as something2 
          FROM [MyTable]
         WHERE <Condition>
       ) yoursubquery
```

Or more simply just type the full column name whenever you need it:

```
SELECT [col1] as something1, [col2] as something2, 
       [col1] + [col2] -- or whatever else you wanted to do 
  FROM [MyTable] 
 WHERE <Condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you wanting to use them, exactly, in the third selection?

You can do:

```
SELECT
  COL1,
  COL2,
  COL1 + COL2 AS COL3
FROM
  TABLE1
WHERE
  COL1 > 0
```

But I'm not clear on what you mean by "using" them.

Comment: "[colN] as somethingN" part is actually a CASE WHEN statement with several branches. It is not just a simple column name.

Comment: So why not state the real problem instead of one with watered-down and simplified details?