# MySQL Case Statement Unknown Cloumn in field list

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Below is the Case statement

```
Select CASE
    WHEN TRIM('@#MDM_COLUMN@#')<>'UNSPECIFIED'
    THEN table.@#MDM_COLUMN@#
    ELSE NULL
END AS mdm_id
from
table
```

THE `@#MDM_COLUMN@#` is a run-time parameter which gets replaced accordingly

if `@#MDM_COLUMN@# = 'UNSPECIFIED'` the query is failing saying

> Unknown column table.UNSPECIFIED in field list

It looks like the behavior of CASE statement is, check the complete statement for syntax and validity before executing, 
So is there any other way to overcome this behavior I need

Comment: Sounds like it's not being replaced (replaced with an empty string?).

Comment: The error message tells that there is NO quote chars around UNSPECIFIED literal... Show the query text AFTER replacing.

Comment: @Akina after parameters are replaced it look like CASE WHEN TRIM('UNSPECIFIED')<>'UNSPECIFIED' THEN table.UNSPECIFIED ELSE NULL END AS mdm_id

Comment: *THEN table.UNSPECIFIED* - and why you're surprised?

Comment: Could this be a reason for your case ?https://stackoverflow.com/a/30243941/8813684

Comment: @NareshKumar It is somewhat similar to the link you shared i.e that respective column in Table doesn't exist and CASE statement is doing a check for that condition even though it has to execute the ELSE part and I want a workaround for this

Comment: @Akina yeah table.UNSPECIFIED is coming as expected but the block that should be running in this scenario is the ELSE part, but instead MySQL is checking the validity for the 1st block as well and only if that is correct then it is executing?

Comment: Server checks ALL query text before query execution. And checks formally - if some field of some table occures then thes field must exist in the table. Use dynamic SQL and apply the selection before PREPARE.