# SQL Why am I getting the invalid identifier error?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, count, aggregate-functions

I am trying to use columns that I created in this query to create another column.

Let me first my messy query. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT tb.team, tb.player, tb.type, tb.date, ToChar(Current Date-1, 'DD-MON-YY') as yesterday, 
       CASE WHEN to_date(tb.date) = yesterday then 1 else 0 end dateindicator, 
       
       FROM (
              COUNT DISTINCT(*) 
                  FROM TABLE_A, dual
                  where dateindicator = 1 
                  Group by tb.team
             )
```

What I am trying to do here is:

1. creating a column with "Yesterday's date"
2. Using the "Yesterday" column to create another column called dateindicator indicating each row is yesterday's data or not.
3. then using that dateindicator, I want to count the distinct number of player for each team that has 1 of the dateindicator column.

But I am getting the `"invalid identifier"` error. I am new to this oracle SQL, and trying to learn here.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver, ...? Also, sample data and desired results would make your question easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an Alias in your Select statement.

see here: [SQL: Alias Column Name for Use in CASE Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583609/sql-alias-column-name-for-use-in-case-statement)

you need to use the full toChar(.. in the CASE WHEN.

Also:
Your WHERE-condition (Line 5) doesnt belong there.. it should be:

SELECT DISTINCT .>. FROM .>. WHERE. you have to specify the table first. then you can filter it with where.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow your explanation correctly: for each team, you want to count the number of players whose date column is yesterday.

If so, you can just filter and aggregate:

```
select team, count(*) as cnt
from mytable
where mydate >= trunc(sysdate) - 1 and mydate < trunc(sysdate)
group by team
```

This assumes that the dates are stored in column `mydate`, that is of `date` datatype.

I am unsure what you mean by *counting distinct players*; presumably, a given player appears just once per team, so I used `count(*)`. If you really need to, you can change that to `count(distinct player)`.

Finally: if you want to allow teams where no player matches, you can move the filtering logic within the aggregate function:

```
select team, 
    sum(case when mydate >= trunc(sysdate) - 1 and mydate < trunc(sysdate) then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from mytable
group by team
```