# MySQL- How to use alias with CASE statement

Tags: mysql

**I want to display First Name, Salary, Tenure and Bonus based on tenure but I am getting this error:**

"TENURE": invalid identifier

This is my query:

```
select 
first_name as "First Name", Salary, 
round((sysdate - to_date(hire_date))/365.25,2) as Tenure,
Salary*(
CASE
when Tenure between 0 and 10 then 0.05
when Tenure between 11 and 15 then 0.1
when Tenure between 16 and 20 then 0.15
when Tenure > 20 then 0.2 
END) as Bonus
from employees;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL: Alias Column Name for Use in CASE Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583609/sql-alias-column-name-for-use-in-case-statement)

Comment: You cannot use output column alias in the expression for another output column. Either repeat the expression or use CTE/subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT AA.first_name as "First Name", AA.Salary,
AA.Salary*(
CASE
     when AA.Tenure between 0 and 10 then 0.05
     when AA.Tenure between 11 and 15 then 0.1
     when AA.Tenure between 16 and 20 then 0.15
     when AA.Tenure > 20 then 0.2 
END) as Bonus
FROM (select 
first_name, Salary, 
round((sysdate - to_date(hire_date))/365.25,2) as Tenure
from employees)) AA;
```

Comment: Nice, that's a good workaround for the alias restrictions.

Comment: This solution works but does not display "Tenure" column. I tried adding it after the AA.salary but doesn't work. I tried this but got error "HIRE_DATE": invalid identifier.   `SELECT e.first_name as "First Name", e.last_name as "Last Name", e.Salary, round((sysdate - to_date(e.hire_date))/365.25,2) as Tenure,
e.Salary*(......`

Comment: This worked for my desired output with tenure column included: `SELECT AA.first_name as "First Name", AA.Salary, round((sysdate - to_date(hire_date))/365.25,2) as Tenure, 
AA.Salary*(
CASE
     when AA.Tenure between 0 and 10 then 0.05
     when AA.Tenure between 11 and 15 then 0.1
     when AA.Tenure between 16 and 20 then 0.15
     when AA.Tenure > 20 then 0.2 
END) as Bonus
FROM (select 
first_name, Salary, hire_date,
round((sysdate - to_date(hire_date))/365.25,2) as Tenure
from employees)) AA;`